# XSL Sorting Numbers by position of nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to sort out the values of "number" by the Position/or first come in the XML document of the T.number values and display it.  Is there a way to do this?

Here is my XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JobList>
<Job ID="2" />                
<Job ID="3" />                
<Job ID="5" />                
<Job ID="4" />
<Job ID="6" />                
<Job T.number="28" />                
<Job T.number="10" />                
<Job T.number="24" />                
<Job T.number="75" />
<Job T.number="75" />                
<Tool number="10" />
<Tool number="24" />
<Tool number="28" />
<Tool number="75" />
<Tool number="75" />
</JobList>
```

Desired Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JobList>
<Job ID="2" />               
<Job ID="3" />               
<Job ID="5" />                
<Job ID="4" />
<Job ID="6" />                 
<Tool number="28" />
<Tool number="10" />
<Tool number="24" />
<Tool number="75" />
</JobList>
```

Here is the XSL document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" />
<xsl:param name="REPORT">joblist</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="LOCALE">en-US</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="FORMAT">html</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="CAPTURE">example,job</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Joblist Report</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Arial;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="JobList">
<div>
<table width="100" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Sorted Numbers" />
</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<xsl:variable name="vsortOrder" select="//Job[@T.number]" />
<xsl:for-each select="Tool">                      
<xsl:sort select="@number" order="{$vsortOrder}" data-type="number" />
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="@number" />
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

UPDATE: I have found an attribute that has the same number order I need.  I updated the XML with the attribute.  But the XSL still doesnt want to sort it out.

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the required transformation.

Comment: The Logic is just for the User to build tooling in order of operation.  When XSL organizes it by accending or decending, that is not the order that the Tools run in and make it more difficult to know what is coming next.

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood my question. Please explain why is 28 first,  10 second, 24 third, and 75 last. What is the **rule** that one needs to apply here?

Comment: There is no rule as what I can think of.  Each ID has a corrosponding Number with it.   There is no specific Order or pattern they come in.  I was hoping I could sort @number using Job@ID because the order it is displayed is the correct order but that didnt work.  I nay have to try a diffrent approach to this Issue.

Comment: I found an attribute that will always display the right order.  I have included it in my question.

Comment: for a rule I guess I could say It has to follow the Order of "T.number" attribute.  If that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output looks a lot different than what your actual code would produce.  But maybe this will help you.  This code will get your desired output.  Then you can modify it to be what you actually want.

```
<!-- Change your for-each loop.  -->
<xsl:for-each select="$vsortOrder/@T.number">                      

   <xsl:variable name="tnumber" select="."/>   

   <xsl:copy-of select="//Tool[@number=$tnumber]"/>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Or, you could modify your code to do this.  Since you are only printing out the number, you do not have to lookup the tool.

```
<!-- Change your for-each loop.  -->
<xsl:for-each select="$vsortOrder/@T.number">                      
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I came across one Issue though.  If I have the same T.number Node, It displays both of them.  Is there a way to only display one of them and not both?  I have updated the question again to show an example with T.number = 75

Comment: You can do this by selecting a distinct list of @T.number, and looping through that instead.  Just winging it here, but it might look like this: <xsl:for-each select="$vsortOrder/@T.number[not(.=preceding-sibling::@T.number)]]">